# Remove "Add to Reading List" from Share Sheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sharing

I've got the native iOS share sheet popping up in my app to allow people to share stuff via social media, iMessage, etc. However, can I remove the entries for "Add to Reading List" and "Copy" that live in there? They aren't useful for my app, so I'd like to get rid of 'em if possible.

Doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6, you can remove the entry for Copy but you can't remove the Add to Reading List item.

Set the `excludedActivityTypes` property on your `UIActivityViewController`:

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard ];
```

If you need more control over the sheet, you may have to use an open source re-implementation like [REActivityViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController).

Comment: Looks like `UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList` does exist, so looks like it can be hidden too :) Thanks!

Comment: In a newer versions of iOS, perhaps ;)